# Highcharts Export Server on AWS Lambda

Tags: lambda, highcharts

Has anybody successfully created a highcharts export server running on AWS Lambda? If so do they have a sample deployment package they might be willing to share.

The general goal is to be able to pass in an image type and chart options as the payload to lambda and have it return an image.

So far I have done the following:

```
# Created a folder and moved into it
cd ../highchart_export_server

# Im building Phantom on OSX do I need to set these to get Phantom to build
# for linux
export PHANTOMJS_PLATFORM="linux"
export PHANTOMJS_ARCH="x64"

# Created a new package and install highcharts per docs
npm init
npm install highcharts-export-server

# Create an index handler -> See the content of that file below

# zip the package up as a deployment and upload it to lambda
zip -r function.zip .
```

#### `index.js`

```js
//Include the exporter module
const exporter = require('highcharts-export-server');

exports.handler = async (event) => {

    var type = event.body.type;
    console.log('Type: ' + type);

    //Export settings
    var exportSettings = {
        type: event.format,
        options: event.options;

    //Set up a pool of PhantomJS workers
    exporter.initPool();

    //Perform an export
    /*
        Export settings corresponds to the available CLI arguments described
        above.
    */
    exporter.export(exportSettings, function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.stack);
        }

        //The export result is now in res.
        //If the output is not PDF or SVG, it will be base64 encoded (res.data).
        //If the output is a PDF or SVG, it will contain a filename (res.filename).

        //Kill the pool when we're done with it, and exit the application
        exporter.killPool();
        process.exit(1);
    });


    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: event,
    };
    return response;
};
```

When I test the function I am getting this error:

```
START RequestId: 97e615c4-5e42-457e-8c8a-02e7001957f5 Version: $LATEST
2019-07-18T15:20:57.128Z    97e615c4-5e42-457e-8c8a-02e7001957f5    ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"write EPIPE","code":"EPIPE","stack":["Error: write EPIPE","    at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:779:14)"],"errno":"EPIPE","syscall":"write"}
2019-07-18T15:20:57.207Z    97e615c4-5e42-457e-8c8a-02e7001957f5    INFO    uncaughtException: { Error: write EPIPE
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:779:14)
  errno: 'EPIPE',
  code: 'EPIPE',
  syscall: 'write',
  [Symbol(aws.lambda.Timestamp)]: 2019-07-18T15:20:57.128Z,
  [Symbol(aws.lambda.RequestId)]: '97e615c4-5e42-457e-8c8a-02e7001957f5' }
2019-07-18T15:20:57.247Z    97e615c4-5e42-457e-8c8a-02e7001957f5    INFO    Thu Jul 18 2019 15:20:57 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [error] phantom worker 1 error - /var/task/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: error while loading shared libraries: libfontconfig.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2019-07-18T15:20:57.247Z    97e615c4-5e42-457e-8c8a-02e7001957f5    INFO    Thu Jul 18 2019 15:20:57 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [error] phantom worker 2 error - /var/task/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: error while loading shared libraries: libfontconfig.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2019-07-18T15:20:57.247Z    97e615c4-5e42-457e-8c8a-02e7001957f5    INFO    Thu Jul 18 2019 15:20:57 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [error] phantom worker 3 error - /var/task/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: error while loading shared libraries: libfontconfig.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2019-07-18T15:20:57.247Z    97e615c4-5e42-457e-8c8a-02e7001957f5    INFO    Thu Jul 18 2019 15:20:57 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [error] phantom worker 4 error - /var/task/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: error while loading shared libraries: libfontconfig.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2019-07-18T15:20:57.248Z    97e615c4-5e42-457e-8c8a-02e7001957f5    INFO    Thu Jul 18 2019 15:20:57 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [error] phantom worker 5 error - /var/task/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: error while loading shared libraries: libfontconfig.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2019-07-18T15:20:57.248Z    97e615c4-5e42-457e-8c8a-02e7001957f5    INFO    Thu Jul 18 2019 15:20:57 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [error] phantom worker 6 error - /var/task/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: error while loading shared libraries: libfontconfig.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2019-07-18T15:20:57.248Z    97e615c4-5e42-457e-8c8a-02e7001957f5    INFO    Thu Jul 18 2019 15:20:57 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [error] phantom worker 7 error - /var/task/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: error while loading shared libraries: libfontconfig.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2019-07-18T15:20:57.248Z    97e615c4-5e42-457e-8c8a-02e7001957f5    INFO    Thu Jul 18 2019 15:20:57 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [error] phantom worker 8 error - /var/task/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: error while loading shared libraries: libfontconfig.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2019-07-18T15:20:57.268Z    97e615c4-5e42-457e-8c8a-02e7001957f5    INFO    undefined
END RequestId: 97e615c4-5e42-457e-8c8a-02e7001957f5
REPORT RequestId: 97e615c4-5e42-457e-8c8a-02e7001957f5  Duration: 620.04 ms Billed Duration: 700 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 81 MB  
RequestId: 97e615c4-5e42-457e-8c8a-02e7001957f5 Process exited before completing request
```

Per the error it looks like `libfontconfig.so.1` is missing but I can't find any way to add it to the dependencies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In response to this I have created a Github repo with a dedicated project specifically for deploying the Highcharts export server onto Lamdba.

Github: https://github.com/tarkal/highchart-lambda-export-server

I have provided both detailed instructions for those wishing to build from scratch as well as a prebuilt zip that can be directly uploaded to Lambda.

> This project contains a fix for the missing fonts mentioned in the comments.

Comment: I had the same task, to place the highcharts-export-server on lambda. Everything turned out thanks to your answer and the zip file attached, with the exception of one thing. The picture is generated successfully, but completely without fonts. Could you tell me what could be the problem? I don’t understand which way to look, what to push from.

Comment: @Nick Please see the new project at https://github.com/tarkal/highchart-lambda-export-server. It contains a fix for the font issue.

Comment: I also got a task to run the export server in Lambda. After fixing dependencies and fonts, I can get images (png, jpg). But I am curious why PDF file wasn't generated. Successful execution but no local file. I also did a recursive search but could not find it. Do you able to generate PDF in your Lambdas?

Comment: @YuriiMaksimov As mentioned in the repo documentation by default this is not setup to return PDF > 'Lambda functions cannot return files directly. So if you are going to convert your chart to a PDF or SVG you will need to create some code to handle writing the file that is created by highcharts to a byte[] (or some other mechanism like S3)'

Comment: @tarka Yes, I understand that but the problem is a file itself does not created. So, no source to make a byte[] from

Comment: @tarka I got the file when I run in amazon linux ec2 but could not get why no file generated during lambda execution.

Comment: @YuriiMaksimov did you ever find a solution for this? I suspect it's not able to write to the lambda file storage.

Comment: @Askdesigners Unfortunately no. Maybe I will return to this question later. I will share the solution if I will find it.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone finding this post in 2021, my advice to you is to completely avoid the export server provided by Highcharts. It's not well written, is full of memory leaks and will constantly clog your logs will error and crash messages.

We successfully moved our chart rendering into a simple headless chrome implementation in much less time than we initial spent trying to get the "ready to use" official render server working.

My advice is to steer clear completely and roll your own.